# Transform xlsx to csv in AIX when there is no tool to do it

Tags: aix, csv, excel

I need to transform xlsx to csv in AIX but there isn't any command installed to do so and it can´t be installed. To make it worse perl don´t have spreadsheet library and python isn't even installed.

Is there still any way to convert that files ?

Edit: Process has to be automatable 
Edit2: it is just a regular exel file 1 sheet with rows but as xlsx is a complex file it is hard to treat if you don´t have the right tools. It is for a powercenter process (witch have hard time with excels so my best option is to transform the excel to something more simple).

Comment: You can’t load it into Excel and export as CSV?

Comment: process has to be automated. Missed that.

Comment: Something generated the Excel file, though?/

Comment: could you at least provide an example of what your working on and what you want. Are you admin on this AIX ? You could have installed the GNU Tools which could help you a lot. You will need anyway a tool to parse XML there's almost no chance you will be able to do without it. Do you have Python install on this AIX and if you have what version ?

Comment: this something don´t cooperate that much it may be possible to get csvs right away and don´t have this issue but it is yet to see.

Comment: @Kiwy added more info. I am a regular user.

Comment: @kifli You realize that transforming Excel file (I though it was XSL I misread) is very complex. I know one Java library but you will need to program in Java... See this thread, it old and never had proper answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10557360/convert-xlsx-to-csv-in-linux-command-line

Comment: @Kiwy yes I realise that there is also libraries for that in perl, python and commands . The options I found on the internet where those 3 but any worked for reasons exposed. I was guessing if there is a 4th option that would not imply more people.

Comment: @kifli You will either to install tools on your AIX or to develop your own solution.

Comment: @Kiwy I could use this as answer because I reached the same conclusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to no common tool you could either ask you admin to install tool such as `ssconvert` (Though I'm not sure there a standalone version of it).
Or you will have to program your own solution using common libraries such as:

- Ruby: `axlsx`,`rubyXL`,`roo`,`creek`,`spreadsheet`,`simple_xlsx_reader`
- Java: `Apache-POI`-> https://poi.apache.org/
- Perl: `Spreadsheet-Read` -> https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Spreadsheet-Read/README
- Python: `openpyxl` -> https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Good luck